# Team Services - Pull Request - Files List not updating when target branch updated

Tags: azure-devops

I have a question about the behaviour of the files list in Pull Requests in Visual Studio Team Services.

**The Situation**
We have 2 branches in our project, Branch A and Branch B, which have the following commit history and 'story' outlined below.

1. Branch A is created off our Development branch.
2. Branch A work is completed and a pull request back to Development is created. Let's call that Pull Request A
3. Branch B is created off Branch A as it builds upon the changes made that were made in that branch.
4. Branch B changes work is completed and a pull request back to the Development branch is created.  Let's call that Pull Request B.
5. Pull Request A is completed with all Branch A changes merged back into the Development branch.

Branch A - Commits
- Commit 1 - File A changed
- Commit 2 - File B changed
- Commit 3 - File A changed again

Branch B - Commits
- All Branch A commits
- Commit 4 - File C changed.

**The Problem and the Question**
When opening Pull Request B in Team Services and viewing the files list.  As Pull Request A has been completed, I expect only to see Commit C changes in the in the files list (i.e. File C).  This is not the case and we actually see all files from commits 1 through to 4.

How do I make Visual Studio Team Services refresh this list so I see an up-to-date list of files to complete my pull request efficiently?

Comment: I can reproduce your issue now and submit a feedback, I updated my answer and you can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I clear your issue now and I can reproduce it. I submit a feedback [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/3112900/vsts-git-pull-request-issue).

The workaround is that you could abandon pervious pull request and create a new pull request, it will just list the last commit.

Comment: Thanks Starain. I ended up coming to the same conclusion regarding the work around - i.e. abandon previous pull request and create a new on - not ideal but does the trick for now.